# How to build a SSO service provider using aacotroneo on Laravel 5.2 and angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, single-sign-on, onelogin

I've been task with building a service provider using Aacotroneo library (a wrapper for Onelogin). The documentation on both project lack code examples of how to make a login page, and how to make actual request to the Idp. Has anybody created a  service provider using Laravel 5.2, angularjs and aacotroneo?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Review this [laravel-saml-sp-demo](https://github.com/taiyeoguns/laravel-saml-sp-demo) project. Is not angular, but a working example of lavarel - saml integration.

Comment: Thank you for your help!